# Conditional Regex to match url

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to make a if/then condition to match the url, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am trying to match URLs and then capture the non-optional group. So - if a url comes in like this:

```
/en/testing.aspx
```

I want to capture `/testing.aspx`

if the url comes in like this:

```
/testing.aspx
```

I want to capture `/testing.aspx`

Is there an easy way to do this using regex?

**EDIT:**

The Url can be multi-part url, like `/en/sub1/sub2/testing.aspx` - I essentially want everything after "`/en/`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a greedy regex which will consume everything up until the final forward slash.  Then, capture everything which comes after that point.

```
^.*?(?:\/en)?(\/.*)$
```

## Demo

Comment: if I have multiple "/", it only gets the last section :-(

Comment: Why frowning?  You told us you only want the last section.  Update your question with what you actually want here.

Comment: Is that a frown? I meant to put a sad face - I must not be up to date on my emoji - anyhow, the question has been updated.

Comment: is it possible to make what I want to capture the first capture group? Or the ONLY capture group?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  My answer only has one actual capture group.

Comment: I'm trying to make a rule for IIS rewrite, and the when I use the above expression, it outputs two capture groups. (C:0) and (C:1) - (C:1) is the one that I need, but somehow it doesn't seem to work. I have a feeling IIS is trying to take (C:0) always, even when I specify (C:1)

Answer (score 1):

use regex `\/en(\/.+)$`

Check this out

edited

https://regex101.com/r/lwowhi/6

If there is "/en/" in the URL and you still want to capture `/testing.aspx` then here is an edit `(?:\/en)*(\/.+)$`

https://regex101.com/r/lwowhi/8

Comment: only captures the last section after "/"

Comment: It was according to your earlier question.

Comment: I made changes according to your requirement

Comment: This misses the edge case of `/testing.aspx`, in which case your regex would capture nothing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, thanks for noticing it. I've made a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing all pages are .aspx then use group.

## regex: .*(/.*.aspx)

> this will match "/testing.aspx" in all bellow samples
>
> /testing.aspx or
>
> /en/testing.aspx or
>
> www.abc.com/en-us/testing.aspx

Comment: not all pages are .aspx - that was just an example.